# Calling ViewGroup#addView and ViewGroup#removeView causes NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-view, android-framelayout

Inside a method, I call [`addView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView%28android.view.View%29) and [`removeView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#removeView%28android.view.View%29) as follows:

```
public class EnclosingClass extends FrameLayout {
    ...
    void fooMethod() {
        ...
        viewGroup1.addView(this);
        viewGroup2.removeView(this);
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

This works fine on portrait mode (it's being called many times without any problem), but as soon as I change the orientation of the screen to landscape, I get a `NullPointerException`: (FYI, `fooMethod` is being called from [surfaceChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceHolder.Callback.html#surfaceChanged%28android.view.SurfaceHolder,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) during the orientation change):

```
 18376         AndroidRuntime  E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 18376         AndroidRuntime  E  Process: com.google.android.apps.chrome, PID: 18376
 18376         AndroidRuntime  E  java.lang.NullPointerException
 18376         AndroidRuntime  E  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:405)
 18376         AndroidRuntime  E  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
 18376         AndroidRuntime  E  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
 18376         AndroidRuntime  E  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
 18376         AndroidRuntime  E  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
 18376         AndroidRuntime  E  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
 18376         AndroidRuntime  E  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
 18376         AndroidRuntime  E  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
 18376         AndroidRuntime  E  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
 18376         AndroidRuntime  E  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
 18376         AndroidRuntime  E  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
 18376         AndroidRuntime  E  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
 18376         AndroidRuntime  E  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1987)
 18376         AndroidRuntime  E  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1744)
 18376         AndroidRuntime  E  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
 18376         AndroidRuntime  E  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5670)
 18376         AndroidRuntime  E  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
 18376         AndroidRuntime  E  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
 18376         AndroidRuntime  E  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
 18376         AndroidRuntime  E  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
 18376         AndroidRuntime  E  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
 18376         AndroidRuntime  E  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
 18376         AndroidRuntime  E  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
 18376         AndroidRuntime  E  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
 18376         AndroidRuntime  E  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 18376         AndroidRuntime  E  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
 18376         AndroidRuntime  E  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
 18376         AndroidRuntime  E  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
 18376         AndroidRuntime  E  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

In order to solve this problem, I put `addView` and `removeView` inside a `Runnable` as follows:

```
void fooMethod() {
    ...
    new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            viewGroup1.addView(EnclosingClass.this);
            viewGroup2.removeView(EnclosingClass.this);
    });
    ...
}
```

This does solve the issue, and everything seems to be working fine, but I don't understand why. How does putting the methods inside the message queue help the issue? Also, why don't I see any reference to my code in the stack trace? I found the issue by commenting out the code gradually.

Answer (score 0):

```
public final void runOnUiThread(Runnable action) {
    if (Thread.currentThread() != mUiThread) {
        mHandler.post(action);
    } else {
        action.run();
    }`enter code here`
}
```

becuase you use runOnUiThread on really UIThread,so the code run on else branch :action.run() which is a serial operation .If other api still run on UI Thread with local mChildCount ,the will encounter NULL pointer,(UI Thread not safe)